# Bash script stuck after e2e tests run

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm running my e2e tests with `Nightwatch.js`. I want them to run with a `bash` script (with the end result of them running in CI).
I am pretty new to bash and here is what i have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# exit on errors
set -e 

export NODE_ENV=development
export LIVERELOAD_DISABLED=YES

npm install
NODE_ENV=e2e grunt build
echo "...Starting Node App"
#start app in the background
NODE_ENV=e2e node server.js &
#save node app process id
NODE_PROC=$!
#wait a bit
sleep 10
echo "...Running Frontend Tests"
NODE_ENV=e2e npm run nightwatch
echo "...Tests Finished... Killing Node App"
kill -9 $NODE_PROC
echo "...Node App Killed"
```

the problem is that the script gets stuck after running all the tests (line: `NODE_ENV=e2e npm run nightwatch`)

the only output i'm getting are the logs and the usual tests output. The script gets stuck no matter if the tests pass, fail, or some do and some don't.
I've tried adding `exit 0` at the end which didn't work (makes sense, since it doesn't execute to that point).

Also, changing `set -e` to `set -ex` didn't change the output.

what am i missing here?

Comment: I haven't worked with `npm`, so I give this only as comment, not as answer: First I don't see a point in adding commands at the end of your script, if you have already verified that the `npm run` command does not return. My feeling is that `npm run` waits for `nightwatch` to terminate, so did you investigate, whether `nightwatch.js` does exit?

Comment: That's the thing, when i run only the tests with ```npm run nightwatch``` they finish and exit. That's i can only assume it has something to do with tue bash script.could you maybe suggest an alternative to what i am doing here?

Comment: @Blueprint: Something in the environment (for instance, the working directory) could be different, when you run it from the script.  I would first verify (maybe using `ps`), that the script really hangs within the npm command. Then I would check, whether _nightwatch_ has been started at all - maybe it hasn't.

Comment: @user1934428 thank you for this direction, since i am new to bash knowing which command to use and what commands there are is sometimes tricky.
So i've added ```ps``` after every execution, here is an example output:
```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
17555 ttys000    0:00.07 /bin/zsh -l 21419 ttys000    0:00.00 
/bin/bash ./run_front_tes
...Starting Node App
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
17555 ttys000    0:00.07 
/bin/zsh -l 21419 ttys000    0:00.00 
/bin/bash ./run_front_tes
21421 ttys000    0:00.00 node server.js
```
of course the ones after the tests doesn't show

Comment: @Blueprint : There is no point in adding a `ps` (or anything else) after the command, as I already told you in my earlier comment: If the command hangs, the `ps` won't be executed either. If the `ps` is executed, you only know that the command does not hang. If it is suspected to be hanging, you need to issue a suitable `ps` from a different console window, to see what processes are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i was looking in the wrong place, the script is completely fine, the issue was that i did not close the connection to the DB inside the tests.
Not sure why that caused the issue, but it fixed it